# regex match and replcae <..> characters

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have a requirement to match all `array<..>` in the entire sentence and replace only `<>` to `[]` (replace <> with [] which have prefix array).

I haven't got any clue to resolve this. It will be great if anyone can provide any clue for this issue?

**Input**

```
<tr><td>Asdft array<object> tesnp array<int></td>
<td>asldhj
ashd
repl array<String>
array
asdhl
afe array<object>
endoftest</td></tr>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<tr><td>Asdft array[object] tesnp array[int]</td>
<td>asldhj
ashd
repl array[String]
array
asdhl
afe array[object]
endoftest</tr></td>
```

Comment: What about, "array<String>"?

Comment: I edited the question to put the relevant parts in backticks. Note that things you put inside `<` and `>` in markdown may disappear unless you put them in backticks for code.

Comment: In any case, if you just need to replace one literal string with another literal string, use `String.replace` - not `replaceAll`.

Comment: You do not need a regex; `str.replace("array<object>", "array[object]")` is enough as @RealSkeptic has already mentioned.

Comment: I have requirements to replace <> with [] which have prefix array.

Comment: @RealSkeptic updated question please take a look.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl updated question, please take a look again

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash updated question straightforward replace function will not help here.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar - Alright. I have written an answer to meet the requirement of your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/n3HfUW/1), `array<(\w+)>` to match the word characters within `array<` and `>` as group 1 and replace the angle brackets with square brackets keeping `array` and group 1 unchanged.

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = """
                <tr><td>Asdft array<object> tesnp array<int></td>
                <td>asldhj
                ashd
                repl array<String>
                array
                asdhl
                afe array<object>
                endoftest</td></tr>
                       """;

        String result = str.replaceAll("array<(\\w+)>", "array[$1]");

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
<tr><td>Asdft array[object] tesnp array[int]</td>
<td>asldhj
ashd
repl array[String]
array
asdhl
afe array[object]
endoftest</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished fairly easily with a simple regular expression:

```
(?<=array)  // positive lookbehind (preceded by "array")
<           // opening angle bracket
(\w+)       // one or more word characters (matching group)
>           // closing angle bracket
```

### Working example

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Example {
    public static String replace(String str, String pattern, String replacement) {
        return Pattern
            .compile(pattern, Pattern.MULTILINE)
            .matcher(str)
            .replaceAll(replacement);
    }
    
    public static String fixHtmlText(String htmlText) {
        return replace(htmlText, "(?<=array)<(\\w+)>", "[$1]");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String htmlText = "<tr><td>Asdft array<object> tesnp array<int></td>\n"
                        + "<td>asldhj\n"
                        + "ashd\n"
                        + "repl array<String>\n"
                        + "array\n"
                        + "asdhl\n"
                        + "afe array<object>\n"
                        + "endoftest</td></tr>";
        
        System.out.println(fixHtmlText(htmlText));
    }
}
```

### Output

```
<tr><td>Asdft array[object] tesnp array[int]</td>
<td>asldhj
ashd
repl array[String]
array
asdhl
afe array[object]
endoftest</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `.replace()`. This method search in a string for a specified character, and returns a new string where the specified character are replaced.

In your case you don't need a regex so you can just write:

```
String replacedStr = text.replace("array<object>", "array[object]");
```

Comment: Updated the question, unfortunately I can’t accomplish this requirement with straightforward replace function. I am looking for regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using regexp here.

```java
public static String replaceMacro(String str) {
    final String pattern = "array<";
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    int fromIndex = 0;

    while (true) {
        int lo = str.indexOf(pattern, fromIndex);

        if (lo >= 0) {
            lo += pattern.length() - 1;
            int hi = str.indexOf('>', lo);

            buf.append(str, fromIndex, lo);
            buf.append('[');
            buf.append(str.substring(lo + 1, hi));
            buf.append(']');

            fromIndex = hi + 1;
        } else {
            buf.append(str.substring(fromIndex));
            break;
        }
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

In case you want to use regexp:

```java
public static String replaceMacro(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(array)<(\\w+)>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    int fromIndex = 0;

    while (matcher.find(fromIndex)) {
        int lo = matcher.start();
        int hi = matcher.end();

        buf.append(str, fromIndex, lo).append(matcher.group(1));
        buf.append('[').append(matcher.group(2)).append(']');

        fromIndex = hi;
    }

    if (fromIndex < str.length()) {
        buf.append(str.substring(fromIndex));
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```